# Multiple fields formula excel

Tags: excel, assets, lookup

I have a question about using formulas in excel.

I have a workbook with 2 tables. 
Table 1 contains planned transports for different assets, and table 2 contains actual arrivals for the same transports.

Table 1 looks like this:

- asset#|from|to  |planned departure|planned arrival |actual arrival|
- 10    |abc |bbb |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 10:00|
- 20    |abc |ccc |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 11:00|
- 10    |bbb |ccc |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 11:00|
- 10    |ccc |abc |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 12:00|

Table 2 looks like this:

- asset#|to |actual arrival|
- 10    |bbb|11.11.2014 09:56
- 10    |ccc|11.11.2014 10:55
- 20    |ccc|11.11.2014 11:05
- 10    |abc|11.11.2014 12:01

What I like to do, is populate the field "Actual arrival" in Table 1 with data from table 2. To do this I will have to look for events in Table 2 which matches the asset#, the site i the field "to",and which is greater than the datetime in field "Planned departure".

Result to look like this:

- asset#|from|to  |planned departure|planned arrival |actual arrival|

  - 10    |abc |bbb |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 10:00|11.11.2014 09:56
  - 20    |abc |ccc |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 11:00|11.11.2014 11:05
  - 10    |bbb |ccc |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 11:00|11.11.2014 10:55
  - 10    |ccc |abc |11.11.2014 09:00 |11.11.2014 12:00|11.11.2014 12:01

Table 1 contains about 1500 rows, and table 2 contains about 5000 rows.

Is this possible with formulas in Excel, or do I have to use VBA or Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Table 1 is named Sheet1 and the Table 2 is named Sheet2 and the data are in Sheet1!A1:F[n] and Sheet2!A1:C[n] then this could be achieved with the following array formula in Sheet1!F2 and then filled down:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10000,MIN(IF(($A2=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000)*($C2=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10000)*($D2<Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10000),ROW(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10000),10000+1)))}
```

To enter a array formula you have to enter the formula without the curly brackets and then press [CTRL]+[Shift]+[Enter] instead of only [Enter]. The curly brackets should then be added automatically.

Because array formulas are slow with whole columns, I have limited this to 10000 rows. If this is to small, you have to increase all the 10000 within the formula.

Sheet1:
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:
[image: Sheet2]

The formula returns #REF if there are no possible arrivals for the departure time. To avoid this wrap the formula with IFERROR like:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10000,MIN(IF((A2=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10000)*(C2=Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10000)*(D2<Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10000),ROW(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$10000),10000+1))),"no arrival in Sheet2 until now")}
```

Comment: Can not get this to work properly. Works in some cases in a test environment, but returns #ref or #i/t when i try it in the actual table. I have a Norwegian version of Excel, and have to change the commas with semicolon. Have tried to change formats, paste values and every different tricks I know, but still can't get it to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: See my edited answer. But the formula cannot return #N/A in my opinion. Please show a data sample where it returns this.

Comment: Hi again. After tweaking this problem for hours, I found out that the problem was some generated fields in Table 2, that returned an #I/T. Problem solved. This formula works great. Thank you Axel!